# How to create directory and save image in it using php

Tags: php, html

I have a code where I am selecting an image and then entering the name of the directory I want to create to save that image. After this, once a button is clicked the directory should be created in the given path and file should be saved in it.

Below is the code I am using:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file"/>
    <input type="text" name="idtest" value=<?php echo $idtest; ?> >
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" multiple/>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'G:/dataset/' . $idtest;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])  ;

    echo $uploadfile;

?>
```

Here in the above code I have not include the create directory part which I still have to work on. Now ideally the variable `idtest` should be appended with `uploaddir` variable so whenever I am printing the value of `uploadfile` the last directory should be the one which I entered in the text box. But its not working. Can anyone please throw some light on why its not working. Thanks

Comment: Because PHP doesn't have permissions to create directories?

Comment: So there is no way I can create directory using php. Is it possible using js.?

Comment: @JayBlanchard what about `mkdir()` in php

Comment: You can use `mkdir()`, but PHP will require permissions to create the directory.

Comment: Is the issue that `$uploadfile` does not contain the directory name entered into `$idtest` or that you are receiving an error when trying to create a new directory? Where does the `$idtest` var get set? Something like `$idtest = $_POST['idtest'];`?

Comment: @SapeTheMape Yes `$uploadfile` does not contain the directory name entered into $idtest. It says error as `undefined variable idtest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this upload script a try. Based on your comments, it seems the first issue is the directory name entered in the form not being added to the full `uploadfile` path. You will need to grab `idtest` from the `$_POST` variable first. I would also recommend using [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move the uploaded file.

upload.php

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'G:/dataset/' . $_POST['idtest'];
    // check if directory exists
    if(!is_dir($uploaddir)){
        mkdir($uploaddir);
    }
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir ."/". basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])  ;

    echo $uploadfile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);

?>
```

Please ensure proper form validation and file name checks for security reasons, but that is beyond the scope of this answer. As the other commenters have mentioned, ensure file system permissions are set to allow writing to `G:/dataset/`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The only change I had to do was to add `. "/" ` at the last in `$uploaddir = 'G:/dataset/' . $_POST['idtest'];`

Comment: But dont know why it says `Notice: Undefined variable: idtest in G:\wamp\www\index.php on line 13` and line 13 is `<input type="text" name="idtest" value=<?php echo $idtest; ?> />`.

Comment: @SAndrew that is becuase `$idtest` has not been assigned yet. You can either define as follows: `$idtest = $_POST['idtest'];`  or change the input to be: `<input type="text" name="idtest" value=<?php echo $_POST['idtest']; ?> />` I would recommend the first option as it is good practice to clean $_POST variables before use.